# Vectores Input en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito recoger todos los inputs por 2 razones:

```
1º Saber cuantos había.
2º Saber cual fue pulsado.
```

El problema es que me devuelve una sola posición

En la vista :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                    echo "  <input type='submit' name='btngolpeado[]' 
                    value='¿ Aquí ? '> ";
                }
```

En el controlador:

```
 $posicion = $request->get('btngolpeado');

         var_dump($posicion);

          for($i=0;$i<count($posicion);$i++){
              if($posicion[$i] != null){
                  echo "posicion".$i."fue golpeada";
              }
              echo "pasada".$i;
          }
```

Pulse el botón que pulse, siempre saca lo mismo :
El var_dump y la ejecución sacan:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "¿ Aquí ? " } posicion0fue golpeadapasada0
```

Comment: Intenta dumpear $request->all() y verifica que esten los inpout dentro de un form, por si acaso

Comment: Si hago eso :
   $posicion =   $request->all() ;
         
    var_dump($posicion);
Lanza un error

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo, tu controlador tiene que importar

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Bien, ahora en tu funcion lo llamas con

```
public function ejemplo(Request $request, $opcional)
    {
```

y ahora úsalo en la función

```
 foreach ($request->btngolpeado as $id => $valor) {
      echo $id . " => " . $valor . "<br>";
}
```